# HtmlWebpackPlugin doesn't output anything

Tags: webpack, html-webpack-plugin

HtmlWebpackPlugin doesn't output anything to the webpack output dir: I have this setup:

```
var config = {
  context: __dirname + '/client',
  entry: {
    main: [
      "./app.js"
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "./public",
    filename: "dist.js"
  },
  devtool: "source-map",
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, 'client'),
        ],
        exclude: /node_modules/

      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        loader: "style!css!less"
      },
      {
        test: /\.css/,
        loader: "style!css"
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    // you can now require('file') instead of require('file.js')
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.json']
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'Webpack demo'
    })
  ]
}
```

however no index.html file is output to public.

I just get this message:

```
      Asset       Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
    dist.js     530 kB       0  [emitted]  main
dist.js.map     638 kB       0  [emitted]  main
 index.html  181 bytes          [emitted]
   [0] multi main 28 bytes {0} [built]
    + 130 hidden modules
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
        + 3 hidden modules
```

Comment: its generating the index.html i can see in you message `index.html  181 bytes [emitted] `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **HtmlWebpackPlugin** simplifies creation of HTML files to serve your webpack bundles. This is especially useful for webpack bundles that include a `hash` in the `filename` which changes every compilation. You can either let the plugin generate an HTML file for you, supply your own template using **lodash templates**, or use your **own loader**.

**wbpack.config.js**

```js
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const path=require('path');

var webpackConfig = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path:path.resolve(__dirname,'dist'),
    filename: 'index_bundle.js'
  },
  plugins: [new HtmlWebpackPlugin()]
};

module.exports = webpackConfig;
```

**Output:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Webpack App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="index_bundle.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

you can do customization also like this
[configuration](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#configuration)

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  title:'sample text',
  filename:'sample.index'
)
```